# What should and shouldn't I cache in javascript?

Tags: javascript, caching

I know that it's a good idea to cache objects that will be used many times. But what about if I will use the following many times:

```
var chacheWindow = window;
var chacheDocument = document;
var chacheNavigator = navigator;
var chacheScreen = screen;
var chacheWindowLocationHash = window.location.hash;
var chacheDocumentBody = document.body;
```

Maybe it is only good to chace stuff between `<html></html>`? Please explain.

Comment: No, saving things like `window` into another variable will not make anything faster.

Comment: None of this is caching, with the exception of `window.location.hash`. All you're doing is creating duplicate references to existing objects.

Comment: I wonder where/why this `cacheX=X` started ... I mean, *what* was/is the rationale?

Comment: @Cameron — With the exception of `window`, all of them are avoiding walking an object tree or searching up through to the default object.

Comment: @Quentin: True. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of caching is to avoid either:

**Typing long names repeatedly**

Every one of your examples has a longer name then the original so you don't get that benefit

**Avoiding making an expensive operation repeatedly** (or a slightly costly operation, e.g. `array.length` before a `for` loop, a very large number of times)

There is no sign that you are getting that benefit either.

You probably shouldn't be copying the references to local variables at all.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty hard to say exactly what *you* should cache.

I wouldn't cache native global objects or things that may change. What you are doing in your example is just creating another reference to the same object.

References to DOM elements should be cached, else you will spend time *to serach for them* again. Also *result* of functions that make heavy operations could be cached.

You can use some profiler and see the performences on different functions to get a hint on what you should cache.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a double edged sword. If you've got some value that's intensive to calculate or requires a round trip to the server, caching that is a fantastic idea. For pretty much all of the values that you specified in your question, you're not buying yourself anything. You're simply replacing one variable reference with another.

Generally speaking it's not a good idea to bog yourself down in these micro-optimizations. Optimizing and improving performance is good, but your time is generally better spent looking for that loop that does way too much work or a fixing bad algorithm than handling this type of case where if there's any improvement at all, you're only looking at an improvement of nanoseconds at best - but again for the values you mentioned you will see absolutely no improvement.